# CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA only in one particular component

Tags: angular

I have a component with a custom html-tag. For this I have to use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA. I can add this in app.module.ts where it is working for all components in this module. But now I forget the information, when I use a wrong html-tag in a component. Is it possible to use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA only for one particular component? Or which is the right way to use CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA?

Comment: if you are using standalone components then yes, it is possible to provide schema just for one component

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? Like Andrei points out, standalone components are the answer here. They're only available in Angular 14+, however.